# How to give a unique name to elements of foreach outside of the loop?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

What I am trying to do is explode some strings from MySQL by /,/, and then somehow be able to refer to these arrays outside of the loop.

This is because, each region, country and province are listed in the $data array in the appropriate order, and I need to glue them together somehow.

For example, inside MySQL there is a string stored as:

```
Regions: Africa, Balkans, South America
Countries: Uganda, Greece, Brazil
Provinces: Ubuge, Athenos, Santa Catarina
```

But I am having a really hard time trying to imagine how to tie these together, remember that sometimes there is only one member in each array, or there can be up to a hundred. But each array always contains the same number.

My attempt is something like this... I can get them to print like this, but I can't save them to use outside of the loop.

```
  for ($i = 0; $i < $numrows; $i++){

            $provinces = explode(',', $data[$i]['provinces']) ;
            $countries = explode(',', $data[$i]['countries']) ;
            $regions = explode(',', $data[$i]['regions']) ;       

            foreach($countries as &$country){

            echo $country;

                }
}
```

Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

What I would like to have the final product look like would be

Place:

```
Africa --- Uganda --- Ubuge
Balkans --- Greece --- Athenos
South America --- Brazil --- Santa Catarina
```

Comment: properly designing the db schema in the first place would solve this.

Comment: That's possible but then it would make all other functionality break. Remember this isn't the final product or even the main purpose of the database, it is just being used as convenience to the reporters.

Comment: breaking db norms is nerve a good start. so fix it now, it will only get worse if you continue to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, an associative array might be a good solution for this, if I understand your issue:

```
$region_list = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $numrows; $i++){    
     $provinces = explode(',', $data[$i]['provinces']) ;
     $countries = explode(',', $data[$i]['countries']) ;
     $regions = explode(',', $data[$i]['regions']) ;       

     // So we don't have to run count every time in the loop
     $length = count($countries);

     // Since it's based of the same numeric index
     for($j = 0; $j < $length; $j++)
        $region_list[$regions[$j]] = array(
          'province' => $provinces[$j],
          'country' => $countries[$j]);
     }
}

// Now to loop through all our data
// For an associative array, we can loop over key => value so $region
// becomes the region name
foreach($region_list as $region => $data) {
   echo "$region --- {$data['country']} --- {$data['province']}";
}
```

Comment: Although I am still struggling to make it so that each region can contain more than one country, and each country can contain more than one region.

Answer (score 0):

db redesign that would work:

regions
id | region

countries
id | country | region_id

Provinces
id | province | country_id

Comment: That is how it is currently designed.

Comment: The information I am given for this particular functionality is in the order I specified above.

Comment: that's not how you describe current design above.or you wouldn't be using explode, look at my schema again, it's 3 tables

Comment: It's also possible with self-relationship. In his case, may be better, as it have minor impact on code (for his comment, looks like it's already in production)

Comment: The regions, countries and provinces are stored as you describe. But each report can contain hundreds of them, I am working on the reports table.

Comment: In my opinion, you should not use an id for a region, because there are by definition no repeats, there is only one "Southeast Asia", or for countries, since There are no two countries with the same name, if there were, how would people differentiate? Same with the province, there is only 1 Arizona in the USA.